# AWS S3 cross account policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I would like to set a policy for a S3 bucket that is restricted to a VPC-ID(using a S3 endpoint). I have two accounts, A and B. I want a IAM user in A to access a bucket in B.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html

> ```
> {    "Version": "2012-10-17",    "Id": "Policy1415115909153",    "Statement": [
>  {
>    "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
>    "Principal": "*",
>    "Action": "s3:*",
>    "Effect": "Deny",
>    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"],
>    "Condition": {
>      "StringNotEquals": {
>        "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
>      }
>    }
>  }    ] }
> ```

Above won't work, but following will:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-111111111111"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Feels like best practices is to use a deny policy. Anyone has an idea why and how solve it?

Comment: The first part does not work because nowhere do you actually grant anyone a permission / allow an action, you only explicitly deny some actions. But a lack of deny does not imply an allow. The second snippet actually allows something.

Comment: You mention both an IAM user and a VPC Endpoint. Typically applications running in VPC do not have IAM user credentials; they have IAM role credentials.

Comment: @luk2302 You are of course correct. I know this. If I combine above it will work! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out you need to allow as-well. Combine both policies and it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).